# pandas_datareader not working in jupyter-notebook (Anaconda)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      3 from matplotlib import style
      4 import pandas as pd
----> 5 import pandas_datareader.data as web
      6 
      7 style.use('ggplot')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

data reader gotta be installed separetly.

if using anacoda, try:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda pandas-datareader
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! it work perfectly well, yo saved my time :)

Comment: is there any other solution which doesn't involve anaconda? i am not using it and can not. pip install pandas_datareader is working but yet jupyter not loading it

Comment: if jupyter aint loading it, you problaby installed on a different python dependence/enviroment