# Pandas_datareader error in jupyter_notebook cannot find module via anaconda or pip, possible typo in package name?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, pandas-datareader

There is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257905/pandas-datareader-not-working-in-jupyter-notebook-anaconda) similar to my question, but mine is slightly different.I am using anaconda to run an environment with all the packages I am using. Running in python 3.7. I run jupyter notebook but the following gives me an error:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
```

Error:

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 import pandas_datareader.data as web
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

I noticed when I installed this module via anaconda:

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

there is a hyphen in the module name (pandas-datareader) but when running import (above) there is an underscore. Could this be the problem?

I tried installing via pip and same error!

Comment: I installed pandas-datareader 0.7.0.

Comment: pip install also has the hyphen: $pip install pandas-datareader